# image "stuck!", using 2 column based document

Tags: latex, tex

I'm relatively new to LaTex and have ran into a weird problem.

I am trying to insert an image into my `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` file and it does insert but in a horrendous place.
I tried centring the image and the `/newpage` command but it doesn't move. the code I use to enter the image is `\includegraphics[scale=1]{IMAGE ADDRESS}`.

I would upload an image for you to see but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `includegraphics` in a figure environment:

```
\begin{figure}[p]
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{IMAGE ADDRESS}
\end{figure}
```

The option `p` could also be

- `h` for here
- `t` for top
- `b` for bottom
- `tb` for "top if possible, bottom if it is too bad"
- ...

See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/5645) for a more detailed answer.

Comment: thanks for answering but no luck, it just won't move from the right column

Answer (score 0):

```
\clearpage 

\begin{figure}[p!]

\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{IMAGE ADDRESS}

\end{figure}
```

this fixed the problem, the main thing being \clearpage , which forces latex to start a new page